# How to apply regular expression on a JSON field to extract certain values from it and store into PostgreSQL Dataabse fron Mule Studio?

Tags: regex, json, mule, postgresql-9.2, mule-studio

Say I have a REST based service that returns a JSON object as under

```
{
    "AlertDetails":
        {
            "start":0,
            "left":0,
            "_itemList":
                [   
                    {
                        "id":"badntp",
                        "text":"The time cannot be synchronized to the configured time server.",
                        "click":{
                                    "text":"Click here to modify your time settings.",
                                    "url":"datetime.html"
                                },
                        "severity":"warning",
                        "occurred":"20121031T10:18:54",
                        "args":null
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"updatesitefail",
                        "text":"The update site cannot be contacted to determine if software updates are available.",
                        "click":{
                                    "text":"Click here to manually check for updates.",
                                    "url":"http:\\\/\\\/xyz.com\\\/support\\\/xyz.html"
                                },
                        "severity":"info",
                        "occurred":"20121105T17:23:24",
                        "args":"[http:\\\/\\\/xyz.com\\\/support\\\/xyz.html]"
                    }
                ]
        }
}
```

Now I have a table in PostgreSQL(say *testTable*) whose structure is as under

```
ID       (string)
Severity (string)
Occurred (string)
```

How can I parse those values from the available JSON field to insert the same into the PostgreSQL Database from Mule ESB studio.

The final result in the testTable should be

```
ID                  Severity        Occured
---------           ---------       --------
"badntp"            "warning"       "20121031T10:18:54"
"updatesitefail"    "info"          "20121105T17:23:24"
```

My configuration file is as under

```
<jdbc:postgresql-data-source name="PostgreSQL_Data_Source"
    user="username" password="pwd" url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/TestDB"
    transactionIsolation="UNSPECIFIED" doc:name="PostgreSQL Data Source" />

<jdbc:connector name="PostgreSQL_Connector" dataSource-ref="PostgreSQL_Data_Source"
    validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0"
    doc:name="Database">
    <jdbc:query key="InsertRecord"
        value="INSERT INTO &quot;testTable&quot;(&quot;ID&quot;,&quot;Severity&quot;,&quot;Occured&quot;) VALUES (?,?,?)" />
</jdbc:connector>

<flow name="testRestFlow1" doc:name="testRestFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        address="http://localhost:8082/index.html" doc:name="HTTP" />
    <http:rest-service-component httpMethod="GET"
        serviceUrl="http://localhost:35798/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/567" />
    <object-to-string-transformer />
    <jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"
        queryKey="InsertRecord" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="PostgreSQL_Connector"
        doc:name="Database" />
</flow>
```

The #[message.payload] will contain the entire JSON string. What will come(regular expression or something else) in `VALUES (?,?,?)` to parse   `#[message.payload]`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [MEL cheatsheet](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/MEL+Cheat+Sheet#MELCheatSheet-JSONProcessing):

> MEL has no direct support for JSON. The json-to-object-transformer can
>   turn a JSON payload into a hierarchy of simple data structures that
>   are easily parsed with MEL.

So use first to transform the JSON into datastructures (maps, lists):

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" />
```

Then we extract the `_itemList` array:

```
<expression-transformer
    expression='#[message.payload['AlertDetails']['_itemList']]" />
```

Then we split this array in individual messages:

```
<collection-splitter />
```

From there the following expressions will evaluate to the desired values so they can be used in the insert query:

```
#[message.payload.id]
#[message.payload.severity]
#[message.payload.occurred]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not get your data using Regular expression, because the language of JSON files is not regular (it is context-free). I recommend you to parse it (use some library for that) and then loop through it and read the values.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't read it properly, I thought it is a question about programming. Can you write a program in your environment? If not, I should probably delete my answer.